# How to pass parameters into an Expression tree?

Tags: c#, parsing, parameters, lambda, expression-trees

I am developing the parser for expressions like this:

```
a1 + a2 + a3 > 0 and b <> "" or c = "source"
```

I want to use expression tree and collect parameters (a1, a2..) while parsing expression. How to pass parameters into an Expression tree?

Edit: I am using .net 4.0

Comment: This does not provide much information to your exact issue... are you developing the tree in a functional language (Haskell, OCaml), an object-oriented one (Java, Scala, C#, C++)?

Comment: Not clear yet, best post some code of your expression tree creation.

Comment: I have own expression tree representation and want to convert it to .net expression tree like Expression<Func<(something here), bool>>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a lambda that takes the parameters you're interested in.  Look at the second example on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx